# Disable "image content" content type in CSWP

Tags: 2013, content-type, query, cswp

i'm on SP2013 Enterprise Edition and have a little problem to solve.

**What i want to achieve**

i would like to display all the new items through all my site collection except the images.
So, for example, if a user creates an article, a page, upload/create a document or add a list item with a custom content type, i would like it to appear in my CSWP. But, if th user add an image, i don't want it to be displayed in my CSWP.

Simple, right?
That is what i thought...

**What I did**

... Until i set my CSWP : here is the query i used (generated by the CSWP manager) :

```
path:"http://mySiteCollection"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
```

So, as you can see, there is no restriction and that is totally normal.
it gives me every new item created in my site collection, and when I have an image uploaded in a Publishing Images Library, the path generated is the one to the properties displayForm .

**What i tried**

In the Advanced mode of the cswp manager, i tried to add a property filter : column ContentType is different of "Image Content", which gives me the following query :

```
path:"http://mySiteCollection"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") ContentType<>0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214*
```

And... it does not work. My images are still displayed and the path is still the one to the properties Form.

i tried with the "Image" Content type and had no more success with it...
Maybe i'm doing it wrong, but i don't know what to do more.

**Do you have any idea on how i could drum out the Images of the search result, please ?**

thanks a lot, have a nice day !

Comment: You can exclude images that are based on the content type "Images" by adding -ContentType=Image to your query. This is the ootb content type for the image library. However, if a user creates an custom content type and add images there, they will show up. Or if they add images to the site assets that are based on the content type "Document" they will show up to.

Comment: However if a user choose to create a document library for an example, you might be able to get rid images by filtering out by fileextensions. -FileExtension=png or -FileExtension=jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```
path:"http://mySiteCollection" 
(contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)
-ContentType=Picture
-ContentType=Image
```

This query will return all items in `http://mySiteCollection` without Picture and Image **Content Type**.

```
-ContentType=Image => Content Type not equal to Image
```

**OR**

Not contains Image and Picture Content Type ID

Query:

```
path:"http://mySiteCollection" 
(contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)    -ContentTypeId:0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214* 
-ContentTypeId:0x010102*
```

Not contains Image Content Type ID query

```
-ContentTypeId:0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214*
```

Not contains Picture Content Type ID query

```
-ContentTypeId:0x010102*
```

This query will return all items in `http://mySiteCollection` without Picture and Image **Content Type ID**.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while working with CSWP. I needed to include a particular content type id, so I used "=" operator. But to my surprise nothing came through in results.

Then I tried "contains" operator, which worked perfect for me.

> **Note**: Your query has "ContentType" property but value looks to be of
>   ContentTypeID, may be this can be a problem

Try replacing ContentType with ContentTypeId in your existing query and see if it solves the problem. If not try using "not contains" operator as in shown below query.

```
path:"http://mySiteCollection"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") -ContentTypeId:0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214*
```

I hope this helps!!